# Jquery fullCalendar removeEvents

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents') is only removing events from the current month and not others.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong? Anyone else come accross this problem?

Comment: Are you pulling events from the server via json?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this question, the user was removing the events from the calendar, but not updating it on the server side. Each time he changed months he was re-fetching the data, which included the removed events.

See [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=216) he filed.